# Spring Boot 2.4.2 Gateway API with Zuul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I'm trying to build an Gateway API using the new Spring Boot Starter Parent 2.4.2 but, for some reason, looks like the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul` isn't supported anymore and doesn't work with the new version! Is there any substitute?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode):

> Zuul 1 and Archaius 1 have both been superseded by later versions that are not backward compatible.
>
> The following Spring Cloud Netflix modules and corresponding starters will be placed into maintenance mode:
>
> - spring-cloud-netflix-archaius
> - spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-contract
> - spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard
> - spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream
> - spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix
> - spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon
> - spring-cloud-netflix-turbine-stream
> - spring-cloud-netflix-turbine
> - spring-cloud-netflix-zuul
>
> Replacements
>
> We recommend the following as replacements for the functionality provided by these modules.

| Current | Replacement |
| --- | --- |
| Hystrix | Resilience4j |
| Hystrix Dashboard / Turbine | Micrometer + Monitoring System |
| Ribbon | Spring Cloud Loadbalancer |
| Zuul 1 | Spring Cloud Gateway |
| Archaius 1 | Spring Boot external config + Spring Cloud Config |

So you'd need to migrate to Spring Cloud Gateway.

Comment: Cool! You know where I can find examples about how to implement those new dependencies? (sorry about my bad english)

Comment: @AlfredoMarin here's one for spring cloud gateway: https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/ - google will probably find you for others too.

Comment: For me this means staying on spring-boot 2.3.x for the time being. Migrating to spring-cloud-gateway is not an easy path to follow.

Comment: sorry to disturb you, I just wanna ask, for you is a good practice to add spring security (JWT) in spring cloud to protect my endpoints or should I do this with something else?